# Webアプリケーションの開発を目的としたフレームワークで、VisualStudioみたいなものはないか

Tags: framework

従来ASP.NETのサイトをVisualStudio（C#/VB.NET）で開発していた人間です。

参考書片手に昨今PHPでの開発に手を出し、簡易なWebサイトを構築することができました。

この開発過程で、フレームワークであるCAKE PHPの利用を挑戦しましたが、VisualStudioとの違いに面を喰い、自身の能力のなさから断念し今回はフレームワークを利用しない形式で仕上げてしまいました。
（MVCモデルを理解できていないんじゃないの？と言われればそうかも知れないのですが．．．）

【質問】
VisualStudioのようにドラッグ＆ドロップの操作で、Webページの大まかなコーディングを生成してくれるようなビジュアルの開発操作に長けたフレームワークがあれば教えてください。
この際、使い勝手の良いフレームワークから開発言語を定めても良いかなぁと考えだしています。JAVA・PHYSON・PHP・RUBYなんでも良いです。

Comment: VisualStudioは「統合開発環境、IDE」です。一方でCakePHPの方は「フレームワーク」で両者の単語の理解が混同されていませんか？恐らく質問として求めているのは**IDE**の方ではないかと思います。

Comment: cubickさん　ご見解ありがとうございます。言われてみればそうですね、すみません。
EclipseでCAKE PHPを採用している方、結構いますものね。その構成が実在するということは当方の聞き方は間違いか．．．。
VisualStudioでの開発は構築作業が視覚化され要所要所プロパティ定義を変更していくことで大まかなWebページのコードを
生成してくれます。こういったものがないのかなぁ？と思った次第です。

WebページのHTML部分は、視覚的操作でコントロール（要素）をペタペタはって仕上げられるユーティリティを使って、
仕上がったHTMLをEclipseに貼って、サイトを仕上げるとかが　一般的なのだろうか．．．．

（HTML・CSS・JavaScript・PHP、各々の参考書は総合的なWebサイト構築に特化した内容では書かれていませんから
エディタでのコーディングで読者を導く傾向にあると思います。
実際商用のWebサイトを構築している方々は、どういったユーティリティを取り揃え、どういった開発手順を踏んでいるのか
一連の構成を知りたいと思うのは私だけでしょうか）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

コメントでcubickさんが言われている通り、IDEとフレームワークは別の意味です。

> VisualStudioでの開発は構築作業が視覚化され要所要所プロパティ定義を変更していくこと

こちらの件でいえば、html/js/css界隈で同じものに相当するのはWYSIWYGですが、
まともなものがないので、これらは直書きが多いです。
Entity FrameworkのようなDAOツールは、現在の主流なPHPフレームワークであればどれでも内蔵しているので、コマンドを叩いてひな形を作ればいいと思います。

なお、実務の開発は以下のようになることが多いです。

・有料デザインテンプレート or デザイナが作ったAdobe XD またはhtmlなどをViewに落とし込む
・SPAを前提とするなら、react/angular/vue+vuexといったライブラリも組み込む
・デザイン調整等は、Google Chrome > F12 > ElementsやConsoleで書き換えて確認
・URLパスルーティング、DAOは予めルールを決める
・railsフォロワーなルールならscafford系機能を活用する
・ビジネスロジック層をCとDAO層の間に明確に設ける場合、scaffordのDAO作成部分だけ使う

Comment: ご見解をありがとうございます。
ただ今文面上の用語一つ一つ調べ理解に努めているところです。
当方の能力のレベルの問題で解釈にもう少し時間を要しますが、回答を頂きながら無反応を失礼と思いましたのでまずはお礼まで

Answer (score 0):

将来的にはGoogleがFlutterを完成させた後にIDEもリリースしそうな感じはしますがね
Googleさんの野望はAngulerJSの頃からかなりデカイ
Angulerは所詮、javascriptの上で成り立ってる物でかつ、独自路線がキツく
学習コストが高い為vueやreactと比べると人気は低いですが
Flutterはもはや、Dartという別言語で開発する為
他のjavascriptフレームワークとは競合しなくなり
Angulerの時とは違う結果になる可能性があります。
また、Flutterは一度に、ios、android、webアプリが作れてしまうという強力なフレームワークなので
そこもまた、全くjavascriptフレームワークとは競合しない部分となり
選択肢として選ばれるケースが出てくると考えてます。
Googleの大逆転劇的な感じでしょうかね
忍んで後の大勝ちを狙うスタイルがなんかかっこいいですよね

話を戻すと
現時点でVSやXcodeのようにIDEのGUIベースでサクサク作っていけてしまうような物は心当たり無いですね。
僕的には上述の通りGoogleがFlutterでweb開発を劇的に楽にしてくれると期待してます。
web開発でVSのような開発手法の登場はもう少し時間がかかるかも知れないですね。

Answer (score 0):

IDEだけではなくビジュアル的な開発という方向だと、
ウェブ用のRADツールを使ったり
WaveMaker https://www.wavemaker.com/
HTML5 Builder in RAD Studio https://www.embarcadero.com/jp/products/HTML5-Builder

クロスプラットフォームのGUIフレームワークをWASM向けにコンパイルしたり
Qt https://www.qt.io/qt-examples-for-webassembly

で似たようなことはできると思いますが、現状主流ではないようです。